# How to accept tcl bitmaps list

Tags: tcl

Is there is a way to get list of bitmap images that come by default with Tcl distribution?

I found a wiki page related to this question
http://wiki.tcl.tk/1419
but it uses already prepared bitmap list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Bitmap images* (as opposed to *bitmaps*, which you should avoid if you can) are images created with `image create bitmap`, and may be listed by filtering `image names` with the assistance of `image type`:

```
proc listBitmapImages {} {
    set bitmaps {}
    foreach im [image names] {
        if {[image type $im] eq "bitmap"} {
            lappend bitmaps $im
        }
    }
    return $bitmaps
}
```

Note that Tk creates *no* bitmap images by default. (There are some default *bitmaps*, as listed on the `Tk_GetBitmap` manual page, but they're **not** otherwise discoverable and ought to be avoided in new code if at all possible. Their portability is also very dodgy in the first place, and the main thing you might choose to use them for — stippling of canvas items — is one of the things that isn't actually portable.)

Comment: But I quite like _bitmap images_ as they're relatively easy to pack into a script as literals. Convert to XBM format and you've got text data suitable to use. (You can even make them two-color images by using a suitable mask XBM.)

Answer (score 0):

Proceeding from the wiki page you reference, the relevant command is

where `.c` is a canvas widget.

The `canvas` man page says for the `-bitmap` option of the `create bitmap` subcommand:

> Specifies the bitmaps to display in the item in its normal, active and disabled states. Bitmap may have any of the forms accepted by [Tk_GetBitmap](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkLib/GetBitmap.htm).

The Tk_GetBitmap man page [lists the built-in bitmaps](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkLib/GetBitmap.htm#M7).

I also see the [source code for `generic/tkBitmap.c`](http://core.tcl.tk/tk/artifact/1d3b9bc99c48bc6ebd89017fb640f39258e079fd) shows how the default bitmaps are instantiated.

None of this helps to deduce how to programmatically list the built-in bitmaps.